# Complex integration?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I’ve read that you can integrate some definite integrals using complex variables. I’m curious as to how this happens in practice - for example, an integral such as

$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos 2 x}{1+\sin^2 x} dx$

has a rather gross and irrational numerical value, but can you integrate this with complex variables in a somewhat easy way? What’s the mechanism (and logic) behind developing this?

Comment: See here: https://www.math.ust.hk/~maykwok/courses/ma304/06_07/Complex_4.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C(0,1)$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$, consider the integral
$$\int_{C(0,1)}f(z)dz$$

Use the standard parametrization of $C(0,1)$, we have
$$\int_{C(0,1)}f(z)dz=\int_0^{2\pi}f(e^{ix}) (ie^{ix})dx$$

Now let's do the integral you posted, note that
$$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2},\quad \sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

thus your integral becomes
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos 2x}{1+\sin^2 x}dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-2\sin^2 x}{1+\sin^2 x}dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{-4-2(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^2}{-4+(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^2}dx$$

Now lets use the substitution $z=e^{ix}$, then $dz=ie^{ix}dx=izdx$ hence $\frac{dz}{iz}=dx$, thus we have

$$\begin{aligned}&\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{-4-2(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^2}{-4+(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^2}dx=\int_{C(0,1)}\frac{-4-2(z-z^{-1})^2}{-4+(z-z^{-1})^2}\frac{dz}{iz}\\
=&\int_{C(0,1)}\frac{-2z^2-2z^{-2}}{z^2+z^{-2}-6}\frac{dz}{iz}=i\int_{C(0,1)}\frac{2z^4+2}{z^4-6z^2+1}\frac{dz}{z}\\
=&i\int_{C(0,1)}\frac{2z^4+2}{z\left((z^2-3-2\sqrt{2}\right)\left(z^2-3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}dz
\end{aligned}$$

Then we see that the poles inside $C(0,1)$ are $z=0$ and $z=\pm\sqrt{3-2\sqrt{2}}$, by residue theorem:
$$\int_{C(0,1)}\frac{2z^4+2}{z\left((z^2-3-2\sqrt{2}\right)\left(z^2-3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}dz=2\pi i\sum\text{Res}(f,z)=(4-3\sqrt{2})\pi i$$

Thus
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos 2x}{1+\sin^2 x}dx=i\int_{C(0,1)}\frac{2z^4+2}{z\left((z^2-3-2\sqrt{2}\right)\left(z^2-3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}dz=(3\sqrt{2}-4)\pi$$

The main reason we sometimes use complex analysis to do real integral is because this could make things much easier. In some cases, the integral can be evaluated by using various substitutions, but is not time efficient and clear. In even worse cases, for example, it is possible that your integrant does not have an elementary anti-derivative, for example $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$. In these cases, using complex analysis might be a good choice.